# mongodb structure for sensor data

Tags: mongodb, time-series, sensors

I am new to NOSQL so please bear with me, I have looked through tutorials and relevant time-series based guides but am still stuck.

I currently am working with 1 sensor but whatever is put in place needs to be scalable to tens of thousand sensors at least. The sensors will be remote and data relayed over GPRS so data may be fetched in chunks every 15 minutes but we would like to store data for every minute from the sensor.

There is time-series data I wish to store such as 
GPS location, energy usage, and charging rate but I am honestly very confused about the database structure to store such data. I was also need to store a list of transactions further down the line. I also need to store non time-series data such as a unique sensor ID, a user the sensor is tied too etx..

There is a mongodb blog [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) discussing time-series and 
[here](http://blog.comsysto.com/2014/05/16/processing-and-analysing-sensor-data-a-diy-approach/) for a single sensor.

These suggest every document should store a chunk of time (e.g. an hours worth of data) with values broken down inside that like this:

```html
{ timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:06:00.000Z"), type: “energy_use”, values: { 0: -1, 1: .. 2: .. 3: 4: 5: 6: 7: 8: 58: .. 59 .. } }
```

What I don't understand is how to link this data to a particular sensor? 
If I had 10 sensors would I still have the same structure with one document storing one hours worth of data? Would that be one document per hour per sensor or one document for all sensors within that hour. Why not have a document per sensor with time series recorded within that?

Sorry If this is come across as a little confused I'm obviously struggling a little with the NOSQL model.

If anyone could offer advice as to how to structure the DB I would be eternally grateful, that or move me towards a more comprehensive understanding.

Answer (score 2):

If you go through this presentation you will find your answer. It talks about modeling 16000 sensor data.

[Time Series Data Modeling](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework?_ga=1.177284327.39498261.1433750807)

You could have data from all sensors in one document if you just wanted to aggregate from all the sensors. But if you wish to query based on sensor IDs it would be preferable to embed the sensorId in the _id field of the document like this:

```
{ 
    _id: "38392"
    data: [however you want to capture, per min, per hour]
}
```